# Downgrade Linux Package Using Yum

Tags: svn, yum

I've currently got a 64-bit version of a package installed (subversion-javaHL to be exact).  I need to roll this back to its 32-bit counterpart.

Is there a way to do this without simply uninstalling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rpm -e subversion-javahl-1.4.2-4.el5.x86_64

yum install subversion-javahl-1.4.2-4.el5.i386
```

The version numbers here assume you're running the latest CentOS/RHEL.  You might run into wrinkles based on dependencies... in which case you'll need to do the same operation with the base subversion package.

Comment: The OP asked for a way to do this without simply uninstalling. The first line uninstalls.

Comment: Yeah, but if you want a package off your system, you have to uninstall it.  I don't know of any one-shot way to replace a package with an alternate arch.  Especially since they can coexist on 64-bit systems.

Comment: If there's no way to downgrade in place, that's fine -- just asking.  I'll keep this marked as answered as it still solves my problem to some degree.  I'll switch that if someone knows how to downgrade in place.

Comment: Might be helpful: add `--nodeps` to force the uninstallation of the package, if the erase is blocked because of dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Yum allows plugins to be installed and the Fedora repo contains a yum-allowdowngrade plugin (not sure about CentOS/RHEL). After installing, you should be able to run the following:

```
yum --allow-downgrade install subversion-javahl-1.4.2-4.el5.i386
```

I have never tried using it though and am not sure if switching from 64-bit to 32-bit would technically be considered a downgrade.

Answer (score 2):

If the --allow-downgrade doesn't work, and there's other things depending on this that won't let you uninstall, you could do this in a single transaction using the yum shell:

```
# yum shell
> remove subversion-javahl-1.4.2-4.el5.x86_64
> install subversion-javahl-1.4.2-4.el5.i386
> run
```

Answer (score 0):

On RHEL the yum-allowuninstall plugin is not available, to do this use `yum downgrade <packagename>`.  This requires one step at a time downgrades, but is likely easier on the dependency engine.